# Reading Odoo Python Traceback

Tags: python, odoo, traceback

I am working on a odoo website, I am not familiar with odoo or python very much and while testing something, the Products page on backend has a XML syntax error I made changes through the backend's debug mode but I made sure to undo those changes before proceeding. Since this still might be the cause of the problem, I'm trying to figure out the file it was modifying.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
        return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
        result = self._call_function(**self.params)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
        return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
        return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
        result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
        return self.method(*args, **kw)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
        response = f(*args, **kw)
      File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 862, in call_kw
        return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
        return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 679, in call_kw
        return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 664, in call_kw_model
        result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1324, in load_views
        for [v_id, v_type] in views
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1324, in <dictcomp>
        for [v_id, v_type] in views
      File "/opt/odoo/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 363, in fields_view_get
        res = super(MailThread, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1383, in fields_view_get
        root_view = View.browse(view_id).read_combined(['id', 'name', 'field_parent', 'type', 'model', 'arch'])
      File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 638, in read_combined
        view_arch = etree.fromstring(view_data['arch'].encode('utf-8'))
      File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68106)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1785, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102455)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1673, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:101284)
      File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:96466)
      File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91275)
      File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:92461)
      File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91757)
    XMLSyntaxError: Blank needed here, line 1, column 19
```

Comment: What you have is sysntax error. Can you put the xml code too

Comment: Im not sure which xml file was changed, I just know it's part of products of the Sales app.

Comment: You will find the xml file name just above the error track read carefully

Answer (score 1):

The error trace shows that there is some syntactical error in an xml file.

After correcting the syntax you will have to upgrade the module.

You can either upgrade the module from the 'App' menu or using '-u' key followed by the name of the module when starting the server.

Thanks